# Horizontal Line Extends Past Table Edge

Tags: tables

I am having an issue with a `tabular` table with the `\hline`s extends past the table edge. I have fixed the problem by using `\cline`s instead, making it go from first to last cell (`\cline{1-18}`), but this seems forced. Is there a reason not to use \hline?

Note I have left one horizontal line as \hline.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{array}

\newcounter{vonecount}
\setcounter{vonecount}{0}
\newcommand{\vone}{\stepcounter{vonecount}\thevonecount}

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{r|C{2mm}|C{2mm}|C{2mm}|C{2mm}|C{2mm}|C{2mm}|C{2mm}|C{2mm}|C{2mm}|C{2mm}|C{2mm}|C{2mm}|C{2mm}|C{2mm}|C{2mm}|C{2mm}|C{2mm}|C{2mm}} 
\cline{1-18}
\multicolumn{1}{|r|}{Section One}                           &   
\multicolumn{17}{>{\centering}p{4in}|}{Part One - Synonyms} \\ 
\cline{1-18}
Question \#     &   
\vone & 
\vone & 
\vone & 
\vone & 
\vone & 
\vone & 
\vone & 
\vone & 
\vone & 
\vone & 
\vone & 
\vone & 
\vone & 
\vone & 
\vone & 
\vone & 
\vone \\
\cline{2-18}
Correct Answer  & 
A & 
A & 
A & 
A & 
A & 
A & 
A & 
A & 
A & 
A & 
A & 
A & 
A & 
A & 
A & 
A & 
A \\
Your Answer     & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & &  \\
\cline{1-18}
\multicolumn{1}{|r|}{Section One}                                       &   
\multicolumn{17}{>{\centering}p{4in}|}{Part Two - Sentence Completions} \\ 
\cline{1-18}
Question \#     &   
\vone & 
\vone & 
\vone & 
\vone & 
\vone & 
\vone & 
\vone & 
\vone & 
\vone & 
\vone & 
\vone & 
\vone & 
\vone & 
\vone & 
\vone & 
\vone & 
\vone \\
\cline{2-18}
Correct Answer  &   
A & 
A & 
A & 
A & 
A & 
A & 
A & 
A & 
A & 
A & 
A & 
A & 
A & 
A & 
A & 
A & 
A \\
Your Answer     & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & &  \\
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Scores}                 &   
\multicolumn{4}{c|}{Correct}            &   
\multicolumn{4}{c|}{Total}              &   
\multicolumn{4}{c|}{Stanine}            &   
\multicolumn{5}{c|}{Percentile Rank}    \\
\cline{2-18}
                        &   
\multicolumn{4}{c|}{}   &   
\multicolumn{4}{c|}{}   &   
\multicolumn{4}{c|}{}   &   
\multicolumn{5}{c|}{}   \\
\cline{2-18}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You have defined 19 columns. `\hline` goes the full width. `\cline` is only going as far as you tell it. So the former will go roughly 2cm beyond the latter.

Comment: However, if I remove a column I have defined. The table doesn't compile whether I remove the extra `&` or not.

Comment: Works for me. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works fine for me provided I remove the extra `&` after deleting the 19th column:

[image: Tabular with 18 columns]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{array}

\newcounter{vonecount}
\setcounter{vonecount}{0}
\newcommand{\vone}{\stepcounter{vonecount}\thevonecount}

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{r|*{17}{C{2mm}|}}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|r|}{Section One}                           &
\multicolumn{17}{>{\centering}p{4in}|}{Part One - Synonyms} \\
\hline
Question \#     &
\vone &
\vone &
\vone &
\vone &
\vone &
\vone &
\vone &
\vone &
\vone &
\vone &
\vone &
\vone &
\vone &
\vone &
\vone &
\vone &
\vone \\
\hline
Correct Answer  &
A &
A &
A &
A &
A &
A &
A &
A &
A &
A &
A &
A &
A &
A &
A &
A &
A \\
Your Answer     & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & &   \\
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|r|}{Section One}                                       &
\multicolumn{17}{>{\centering}p{4in}|}{Part Two - Sentence Completions} \\
\hline
Question \#     &
\vone &
\vone &
\vone &
\vone &
\vone &
\vone &
\vone &
\vone &
\vone &
\vone &
\vone &
\vone &
\vone &
\vone &
\vone &
\vone &
\vone \\
\hline
Correct Answer  &
A &
A &
A &
A &
A &
A &
A &
A &
A &
A &
A &
A &
A &
A &
A &
A &
A \\
Your Answer     & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & &   \\
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Scores}                 &
\multicolumn{4}{c|}{Correct}            &
\multicolumn{4}{c|}{Total}              &
\multicolumn{4}{c|}{Stanine}            &
\multicolumn{5}{c|}{Percentile Rank}    \\
\cline{2-18}
                        &
\multicolumn{4}{c|}{}   &
\multicolumn{4}{c|}{}   &
\multicolumn{4}{c|}{}   &
\multicolumn{5}{c|}{}   \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

I'm not sure if that is quite what it is meant to look like but it solves the problem identified in the question. You might want to read the `booktabs` documentation, though.

Comment: Must have missed one when I did it. It works great.